# A word to describe "manually" doing something — not technologically or screen-based

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, synonyms

Example, I want to say something like "manual highlighting," to differentiate between highlighting something on the screen. A word to describe the process of using an actual yellow highlighter (a physical object). Is there another word for this?

Comment: "Highlight with a pen" seems like the best option, though it's more than one word.

Comment: "Manual highlighting" could also apply to on-screen highlighting, in the sense that one manipulates a mouse or uses the keyboard to directly control what is highlighted, as compared to, say, automatic highlighting of typos.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ***[highlight:](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/highlight)***

> 3. To mark (important passages of text) with a usually fluorescent marker as a means of memory retention or for later reference.
>
>    - The spelling mistakes in the text had been highlighted in green.

(AHD)

***[Highlighter:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/highlighter)***

2. countable noun

   > A highlighter is a pen with brightly-coloured ink that is used to mark parts of a document.

(Collins Dictionary)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99483/discussion-on-answer-by-user067531-a-word-to-describe-manually-doing-something).